# Jquery MouseMove infinity loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup

I try to handle mouse move when mouse button is clicked. But when mouse button is released, mouse move event still works. Where is the problem and how to solve the problem?

Example:

```
clicked=false;
var counter =0;
$(document).mousedown(function(){
  clicked=true;
  $(".clicked").text(clicked);
  if(clicked){
    $(document).mousemove(function(){
      $(".mm").append(++counter+" "+clicked+"<br>");
    });
  }
});
$(document).mouseup(function(){
  clicked=false;
  $(".clicked").text(clicked);
  $(".mm").html("mouseup, clicked: "+clicked+"<br>");
})
```

JSFidle:https://jsfiddle.net/r6hb3csp/1/

Even if clicked is false, mousemove event works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check on the BOOLEAN clicked if it ture do your action if not do nothing
Or 
you can  unbind your event after `mouseup`
like that:-

```
clicked=false;
var counter =0;
$(document).mousedown(function(){
    clicked=true;
    $(".clicked").text(clicked);
    if(clicked){
        $(document).mousemove(function(){
            $(".mm").append(++counter+" "+clicked+"<br>");
        });
    }
});
$(document).mouseup(function(){

    clicked=false;
    $(".clicked").text(clicked);
    $(".mm").html("mouseup, clicked: "+clicked+"<br>");
    $(document).unbind("mousemove");
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r6hb3csp/7/

Comment: unbind of event is also important here like **$(document).unbind('mousemove').mousemove(** ///

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
clicked=false;
var counter =0;
$(document).mousedown(function(){
    clicked=true;
    $(".clicked").text(clicked);
    if(clicked){
            $(".mm").append(++counter+" "+clicked+"<br>"); 
    }
});
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clicked=false;
    $(".clicked").text(clicked);
    $(".mm").html("mouseup, clicked: "+clicked+"<br>");
})
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/r6hb3csp/6/)